# How do I create user specific page with Django?

Tags: django

so I've just started studying Django, and ran into a problem.
I'm trying to create a user-specific page, in which if user logs in and inputs his/her info, the info is displayed on the screen, dynamically of course.
So let me show you the codes I wrote.
Here's models.py

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    authuser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'userinfo', null=True, 
    default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    introduction = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And here's views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/register")
def main(response):
    thisUser = # I have no idea on which code to write here.
    return render(response, 'main.html', {'thisUser' : thisUser})
```

And here's the html file, main.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{{thisUser.name}}
{{thisUser.introduction}}
{% endblock %}
```

So this is what I've done so far. I have completed all the registration/login/logouts, as well as the forms for letting users input their info(name, introduction). And the next step I'm trying to take is this user specific page, but I have no idea on how to create it.
I would very much appreciate your help. Thanks. :)

Comment: you should read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#authentication-in-web-requests)

Comment: May i think UserInfo model have `OneToOne` relation with `User model`

Comment: yup unless you don't want to create multiple objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You user `OneToOneField` in Your `UserInfo` model as i give

```
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    authuser = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'userinfo', null=True, 
    default=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    introduction = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Then `makemigrations` and then `migrate`

I think you done login/singup with `user model`

after login what ever page you render that write only the give line
@in you html file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

Name         : {{ request.user.userinfo.name }}
Introduction : {{ request.user.userinfo.introduction }}

{% endblock %}
```

If you face problem with extends user of onetoone field i give link refer it

- [User extends for profile or info](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone)
- [Sing up with profile](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-profile-model)
- [Login of user](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/06/27/how-to-use-djangos-built-in-login-system.html)

if still you have problem let me know..!

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by accept answer to right?

Comment: as i told you use `OneToOneField` and you use that right i give hint And i commet out above question's and answer you see that, it's work fine so it means the my answer is right so you must accept the my answer as right for your quetions

Answer (score 0):

better to change user field to onetoone field

```
thisUser = UserInfo.objects.get(authuser=request.user)
```

(also change def main(response) to def main(request)/same in render also)

request.user will give you current login user object

you can do same in template example:

```
<h1>Name: {{request.user.name}}</h1>
```

Comment: after changing `def main(response)` to `def main(request)`.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot :) But then this time I ran into this problem : UserInfo matching query does not exist. What does this mean?

Comment: are you currently login? with /admin or with your own custom login page

Comment: Well I've tried both with the superuser account and ordinary(?) account. But both didn't work :(

Comment: did you create objects in the UserInfo table, and changes response to request as mentioned?

Comment: Yup I did exactly as you told me to. :( What does that error mean by the way?

Comment: First you used `OneToOne` relation with `UserInfo Model`

Comment: instead of objects.get ,use objects.filter since you are not using oneto one

Comment: Thanks. Now the error is gone, but now the page shows nothing. All I see is empty page :(

Comment: did you use the filter or you convert it to onetoone field and you did change the response to request in the return statement also

Comment: I changed the ForeignKey into OnetoOneField and it worked. Thank you very much :)